# Change search query after adding a new column to table rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Right now I use this search to find items for certain category in my database

```
 @items=Item.where(:category_id => @active_category_id).order(:price)
```

But recently I added a column to `Item` table called `detail`. It can be 0 or 1 and it is `integer` or it can be empty cause I added it just now and I had already some items in my db.
So now I need two searches: I need search that returns items with `detail=1`

And where `detail` is not 1.
So I do it like this:

`#for items with detail = 1`

`@items=Item.where(:category_id => @active_category_id)
.where(:detail=> 1).order(:price)`

It is working.

But now I need to find items with `detail != 1`

So I write

`@items=Item.where(:category_id => @active_category_id)
.where.not(:detail=> 1).order(:price)`
And it is not working. What do I do?

Comment: which version of rails are you using? `where.not()` was introduced in Rails 4

Comment: @TheGeorgeous `gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'`

Comment: What is the generated output and th SQL query? Can you update it in the question?

Comment: @Pavan `SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."category_id" = ? AND ("items"."detail" != ?) ORDER BY "items"."price"`

Comment: Next time you add a new column, you can avoid this hassle by using ", default: [default value]" in your migration. This way, old rows will be the value you want instead of nil. Example: `add_column :items, :detail, :integer, default: 0`. You can also rollback the old migration and change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NULL` values will not match an equality or inequality. You have to explicity compare to `NULL`. Try `Item.where(detail: nil)`.

If you need `0` OR `NULL` you might need to write raw SQL: `Item.where("detail = 0 OR detail IS NULL")`

You might also consider backfilling your db to eliminate the `NULL` values, then you can just compare with 1 and 0.